# Cannot click Evernote clipper from Google Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, evernote

Why can't I click the Evernote clipper from Google Chrome?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think my answer should work for you.

Comment: I'll try @Mark Yisri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation to anyone who encounters a similar problem: if Chrome fails, another browser should work.

Try these browsers (you may even like them better):

1. [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) (or [Adblock Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.browser), which is Firefox with an adblocker)
2. [Puffin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree) (Flash browser, allows you to play Adobe Flash content)
3. [Opera Mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native) (or [Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.browser))
4. [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) (thought this used to be called Dolphin Browser Mini)

Now if it still doesn't work, then you can try the [Evernote for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote) app and use [these instructions](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2015/01/25/clip-web-content-evernote-using-android-ios-devices/) to clip.

In general on Android, it is better to use an app if it exists, as the interface is designed for mobile use. Evernote's clipper is designed for desktop users, but the mobile app should have an interface for clipping in mobile browsers.

Comment: I have the Evernote for Android and it is ineffective

Comment: Opera and opera mini don't work

Comment: @kouty try this: https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2015/01/25/clip-web-content-evernote-using-android-ios-devices/

Comment: did it work to do that?

Comment: @kouty inserted now.